# "Cannot extract single value from Iterable" with custom query result object

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using **SpringDataNeo4J 3.0.0-M1** with **Neo4J 2.00-M0.6**.

I have BetDAO nodes, linked to a collection of BetAnswerDAO nodes with BET_ANSWER relationship.

I'm trying to retrieve a bet and all its answers on the same request. I have a BetRepository with the following request :

```
@Query("start bet=node:BetDAO(id = {betId}) "
    + "match (bet)-[:BET_ANSWER]->(betAnswer) "
    + "return bet, collect(betAnswer) as betAnswers")
BetWithInfo getByIdWithInfo(@Param("betId") String id);
```

My BetWithInfo object :

```
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.QueryResult;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.ResultColumn;

import fr.project.commons.data.graph.neo4j.beans.nodes.BetAnswerDAO;
import fr.project.commons.data.graph.neo4j.beans.nodes.BetDAO;

@QueryResult
public interface BetWithInfo {

    @ResultColumn("bet")
    BetDAO getBet();

    @ResultColumn("betAnswers")
    Iterable<BetAnswerDAO> getBetAnswers();
}
```

The request is executed without errors, but when I try to access the bet answers collections, I get the following error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot extract single value from Iterable with more than one elements.
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.DefaultConverter.extractSingle(DefaultConverter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.DefaultConverter.extractValue(DefaultConverter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.DefaultConverter.convert(DefaultConverter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.EntityResultConverter.convert(EntityResultConverter.java:165)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1.convert(QueryResultBuilder.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1.access$300(QueryResultBuilder.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1$1.underlyingObjectToObject(QueryResultBuilder.java:121)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.next(IteratorWrapper.java:47)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.addToCollection(IteratorUtil.java:403)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.addToCollection(IteratorUtil.java:482)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.asCollection(IteratorUtil.java:581)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.EntityResultConverter.extractAndSetValueOfField(EntityResultConverter.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.EntityResultConverter.extractPOJOResult(EntityResultConverter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.EntityResultConverter.convert(EntityResultConverter.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.DefaultConverter.convert(DefaultConverter.java:36)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase$SpringResultConverter.convert(SpringRestGraphDatabase.java:148)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.QueryResultBuilder$1$1.underlyingObjectToObject(QueryResultBuilder.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.next(IteratorWrapper.java:47)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.single(IteratorUtil.java:334)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.singleOrNull(IteratorUtil.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.singleOrNull(IteratorUtil.java:287)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringEndResult.singleOrNull(SpringEndResult.java:39)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.dispatchQuery(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery$1.doWithGraph(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.doExecute(Neo4jTemplate.java:408)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.access$000(Neo4jTemplate.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate$2.doInTransaction(Neo4jTemplate.java:422)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.exec(Neo4jTemplate.java:419)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:80)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:337)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    ... 59 more
```

It seems to me that what I've done is really close from the example in [spring-data documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/programming-model.html#reference_programming-model_mapresult). What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT :** 
I made a mistake in my code. I get this error when the getBetAnswers() function returns an Iterable. With a Collection, I get the following error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1 cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure

```
@Query("start bet=node:BetDAO(id = {betId}) "
+ "match (bet)-[:BET_ANSWER]->(betAnswer) "
+ "return bet, collect(betAnswer) as betAnswers")
BetWithInfo getByIdWithInfo(@Param("betId") String id);
```

returns only 1 result?

From what I understand, this query returns several rows at runtime but Spring Data is told to return only 1 BetWithInfo.

Either double-check your query thus making sure it returns only 1 row, or migrate your method return type from `BetWithInfo` to `Iterable<BetWithInfo>` (or `Collection<BetWithInfo>`).

Comment: The request returns only one row in Neo4j browser. 
If I change my method return type to an Iterable, I get a list with one BetWithInfo object, and I get the same error when calling getBetAnswers(). 
I have no trouble calling getBet(), the error only occurs when trying to access an Iterable/Collection.

Comment: I guess it would help if you show the result of your manually executed query.

Answer (score 0):

In the BetWithInfo interface, try changing

```
Collection<BetAnswerDAO> getBetAnswers();
```

to

```
Iterable<BetAnswerDAO> getBetAnswers();
```

Answer (score 0):

I looks like it is a bug as described here [google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/21seYtSjRCU). that will be fixed on the next spring-data-neo4j release. 
It is still present in `spring-data-neo4j 3.3.0.RELEASE`.