# How to iterate from QueryResultBuilder using COLLECT() with Cypher

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Spring Neo4j 3.3 version and creating entities via cypher .I have Repo class where i want to fetch the below but getting error as

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot extract single value from Iterable with more than one elements.
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.DefaultConverter.extractSingle(DefaultConverter.java:61) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.DefaultConverter.extractValue(DefaultConverter.java:52) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.DefaultConverter.convert(DefaultConverter.java:41) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.EntityResultConverter.convert(EntityResultConverter.java:165) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1.underlyingObjectToObject(QueryResultBuilder.java:86) ~[spring-data-neo4j-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]

**ReservRepo** :

```
@Query("MATCH (guest:Guest)-[rel:GUEST_RESV]->(reserv:Reserv)-[histRel:RESV_HISTORY]->(resvhistory:ReservHistory) WHERE reserv.id={0} "
            + "  Return guest , COLLECT(resvhistory) as history ")

Collection<GuestHistory> getGuestReservationHist(String reservId);

    @QueryResult
    public interface GuestHistory {

        @ResultColumn("guest")
        GuestProfile getGuest();

        @ResultColumn("history")
        List<ReservHistory> getHistory();


    }

/* Fetching Guest History object */ 
Iterator<GuestHistory> iterator = historyObj.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            GuestHistory hist = iterator.next();
            reservation.setGuest_firstName(hist.getGuest().getFirstName());
            reservation.setGuest_lastName(hist.getGuest().getLastName());
            reservation.setGuest_mobile(hist.getGuest().getMobile());
            reservation.setGuest_email(hist.getGuest().getEmailId());
            reservation.setVIP(hist.getGuest().getIsVip());
            for(ReservHistory history:hist.getHistory()){ /*hist.getHistory() :Error*/                                                                 
                System.out.println("---history---"+history);
            }
            resevation.add(reservation);

        }
```

Please give me direction how to proceed from here or pls share any example

Comment: Doesn't that Cypher return more than one row?

Comment: yes this cypher return more than one row .

Comment: Did you try to use `List<ReservationHistory> getHistory()` instead of `Iterable<ReservationHistory> getHistory()`?

Comment: No luck ...i followed the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705762/cannot-extract-single-value-from-iterable-with-custom-query-result-object?rq=1. Here I am able to get the Guest object but not able to get Collection .

Comment: It works on Spring Data Neo4j 3.4.0.M1 with Neo4j 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

The Cypher query returns more than one row, but you are asking SDN to map it to a single `GuestHistory`. Try

```
@Query("MATCH (guest:Guest)-[rel:GUEST_RESV]->(reserv:Reserv)-[histRel:RESV_HISTORY]->(resvhistory:ReservHistory) WHERE reserv.id={0} "
            + "  Return guest , COLLECT(resvhistory) as history ")
Collection<GuestHistory> getGuestReservationHist(String reservId);
```

Comment: **Still getting the same error as java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot extract single value from Iterable with more than one elements. **                                                                                                               Iterator<GuestHistory> iterator = historyObj.iterator();                      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
GuestHistory hist = iterator.next();    
List<ReservHistory>hist.getHistory());//throws error
}

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and the line in your code that this exception originates from

Comment: Edit the post with full stack trace and line of code where exception occurs. i read the different post on google and found this is a bug in Spring data Neo4J 3.3 .There may be some other mechanism to get it same but don't know :)